# Monitoring changes in web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser

I want to monitor changes in background in complex web application. This is one-page application with many scripts and so on. I need to be logged in to have access to data I want to monitor.

I tried to use webrequest, but I think that the application is to complex to do it that way. There is also a problem with authentication.

I also tried `WebBrowser` component, but web application is telling me, that this browser is too old and I should get newer one.

Perfect solution would:

1. Open this web application in chrome (or some other modern browser) in background
2. Save the page to memory
3. Extract values using something like `HtmlAgilityPack`

While this will be happening I want to normally use the computer (so opening chrome window is not a good solution for me).

Is there any way to achieve something like that?

Comment: What kind of changes do you want to monitor? are you try to monitor data that is getting pushed to the server or just user clicks/interactions?

Comment: @dbarnes there are some numbers shown on the page. I want to monitor them. I need source of page and I can parse it by HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Why can't you just parse the values on the client side and just send what you need, using Jquery or other front end libraries? I will make your requests much lighter.

Comment: Better still, create a web service and use it to produce the numbers on the page. Then you can call the web service to get the numbers, without messing around scraping the web site.

Answer (score 0):

if you can cope with an extra browser running, have a look at [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). with its webdriver-backed selenium you can start a dedicated browser instance and perform user actions by coding in high-level programming languages like java. it should not interfere your manual work at all, but will take up the same amount of memory and cpu time your "real" browser would.

if the web application has no captcha and does not object to automated script accessing it, you could also login in a background program by sending appropriate HTTP requests and parse the response. python's [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) would be my first choice.

if you dont want any additional processes running, you could also create a browser plugin, that autorefreshs and parses a certain open tab every few seconds.